# Update set of fields in django model passed in request.POST

Tags: django

This is my Model class

```
class SubJobs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    subjob_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,help_text="Enter subjob name")
    subjobtype = models.ForeignKey(SubjobType)
    jobstatus = models.ForeignKey(JobStatus, default= None, null=True)
    rerun = models.ForeignKey(ReRun,help_text="Rerun")
    transfer_method = models.ForeignKey(TransferMethod,help_text="Select transfer method")
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority,help_text="Select priority")
    suitefiles = models.ForeignKey(SuiteFiles,help_text="Suite file",default=None,null=True)
    topofiles = models.ForeignKey(TopoFiles,help_text="Topo file",default=None,null=True)
    load_image = models.NullBooleanField(default = True,help_text="Load image")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Enter description",null=True)                           command = models.TextField(help_text="Command",null=True)
    run_id = models.IntegerField(help_text="run_id",null=True)
    pid_of_run = models.IntegerField(help_text="pid_of_run",null=True)
    hold_time = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,null=True)
    finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

The user might want to update a entry and may choose to update only few fields among these. How do I write a generic update statement that would update only the fields that were passed?

I tried this.

```
def update_subjob(request):
if (request.method == 'POST'):
    subjobs_subjobid = request.POST[('subjob_id')]
    post_data = request.POST
    if 'subjob_name' in post_data:
        subjobs_subjobname = request.POST[('subjob_name')]
    if 'subjob_type' in post_data:
        subjobs_subjobtype = request.POST[('subjob_type')]
    if 'rerun_id' in post_data:
        subjobs_rerun_id = request.POST[('rerun_id')]
    if 'priority_id' in post_data:
        subjobs_priority_id = request.POST[('priority_id')]
    if 'transfer_method' in post_data:
        subjobs_transfermethod = request.POST[('transfer_method')]
    if 'suitefile' in post_data:
        subjob_suitefile = request.POST[('suitefile')]
    if 'topofile' in post_data:
        subjob_topofile = request.POST[('topofile')]
    try:
        subjobinstance = SubJobs.objects.filter(id=subjobs_subjobid).update(subjob_name=subjobs_subjobname,
                                 updated=datetime.now())

    except Exception as e:
        print("PROBLEM UPDAING SubJob!!!!")
        print(e.message)
```

How do I write a generic update to update only those fields which are sent in `request.POST`?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what forms are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use Forms. But if you insist on your code it could be done like this.

Suppose you have variable `field_to_update` where every field that you are waiting in request is listed.

```
subjobs_subjobid = request.POST[('subjob_id')]

field_to_update = ('subjob_name','subjob_type', 'rerun_id', 'priority_id', 'transfer_method', 'suitefile', 'topofile')
post_data = request.POST
to_be_updated = {field: post_data.get(field) for field in field_to_update if field in post_data}
# then you need to get the object, not filter it
try:
    subjobinstance = SubJobs.objects.get(id=subjobs_subjobid)
    subjobinstance.update(**to_be_updated, updated=datetime.now())
except ObjectDoesNotExist:  # from django.core.exceptions
    print('There is no such object')  # better to use logger
except Exception as e:
    print("PROBLEM UPDAING SubJob!!!!")
    print(e.message)
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I needed.